# Fast moving actuators?

Tags: actuator

I have a system where I have fairly quick moving actuators.  Their moving about 2' in 214ms and 440ms respectively.  So:

```
24" / (214ms/1000) = 112.1495"/s
24" / (440ms/1000) = 54.54545"/s
```

Currently we are using pneumatic air cylinders to do this, however there is too much variation in the rise time of a pneumatic air cylinder, which is causing constant tuning of the system.

**Are there other actuator's out there that people may be using, that can achieve these speeds with a more consistent rise time?**

I'm an electrical engineer, and I'm getting mixed information from other engineer's I'm consulted.  People have brought up electrical actuators that can work at high speeds, pinons or gantry systems.  Just curious if anyone out there has great experience on this.

Comment: Electromechanical would probably suit you better

Answer (score 0):

What is the mass you are trying to move? The inertia will limit the acceleration you can get out of a given force. Do you have to move over the entire 2 ft? Do you need to achieve that speed exactly or do you just need to move at least that fast?

You might be able decrease the variability of your pneumatic air cylinders with closed loop control with an electronic controller such as an electronic pressure regulator (EPR) or mass flow controller (MFC), although there is not enough information to know of this is applicable to your system.

I don't think any ball screw/lead screw linear actuators would apply because those don't usually reach the speeds you are specifying.

One other option depending on your budget constraints are voice coil motors. These are much more consistent and again, with closed loop control, you can achieve very fast point to point positioning, although the range of motion usually isn't large. I don't think there are any off the shelf voice coils with a range of motion of 2 ft.

By the way, does it have to move that fast in both directions? If it only needs to move in one direction, and you don't mind that it moves faster than what you specified, you could just preload the moving part with a spring which is a cheap solution to boost your acceleration.